# Node; default value if readable stream throws an error

Tags: node.js, stream

I have the following situation, where a reading stream pipes to a writing stream:

```
let rs = fs.createReadStream(getSrcFileName());
let ws = fs.createWriteStream(getTrgFileName());

rs.pipe(ws);

// ...
```

This works just fine. Now, I want to ensure **something always gets written to the file at `getTrgFileName()`, even when `rs` encounters an error**. If an error occurred, I'd like the content in the output file to be `'error occurred'`.

For example, currently if `getSrcFileName()` refers to a non-existent file the entire setup fails and nothing is written to the output file. What stream operations can I apply to generate a default value upon error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the on error handler, and write to the file that way...

```
const fs = require('fs');

rs.on('error', (error) => {
    fs.writeFile('YourFileName.txt', 'error occurred', (err) => { 
      if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File saved, but with errors!');
    });
});
```

Or, if you wanted to just chain it directly to what you're already using....

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rs = fs.createReadStream(getSrcFileName());
let ws = fs.createWriteStream(getTrgFileName());

rs.pipe(ws)
  .on('error', (error) => {
     fs.writeFile('YourFileName.txt', 'error occurred', (err) => { 
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('File saved, but with errors!');
     });
   });
```

Edit:
To continue with your writestream...

```
rs.pipe(ws)
  .on('error', (error) => {
     ws.write('error occurred');
   });
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but could it be made more elegant by feeding the default value down the pipe instead of performing a `fs.writeFile` operation? There's already a writeStream open; I'd like to use it if possible.

Comment: @GershomMaes You can just use the reference to your write stream, and invoke `ws.write('some data')`.  If the issue is that you have an undefined/null file name, then just declare some default file name in case nothing is found.  Like:  `const fileName = getTrgFileName() || 'GenericName.txt';`

Comment: your suggestions are all valid and very pragmatic, but I'm realizing that I formed this question as if the goal is only to write the output to a file. I'm more interested in generally converting streaming errors into default values, without necessarily knowing what the output stream is. I'm going to accept this answer and ask a similar, but more refined question.